# Show $T(y_n)$ is a Schauder basis when $y_n$ is a Schauder basis.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in L(ℓ^2,H)$ and $(y_n)_{n≥1}$ is a Schauder basis in $ℓ^2$ .
Show that if T is a bijective operator then $(T(y_n))_{n≥1}$ is Schauder basis in H.
My attempt :
let $x \in \ell^2$ then $Tx \in H$
since $(y_n)_{n≥1}$ is a Schauder basis in $ℓ^2$ .then $\forall x\in \ell^2$ $\exists a_n \in \ell^2$ such that $||x-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} a_n y_n||\rightarrow0 $. 
$||Tx-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} a_n Ty_n||=||T(x-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} a_n y_n)||$ (T is linear and continuous) Hence $||Tx-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} a_n Ty_n||\rightarrow0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to prove anything think about what you want to show, then proceed. Let me show you. I start with saying to myself "I want to show $\{Ty_n\}$ is a Schauder basis. Then what i should do at the start is to pick an element from $H$.

Let $x\in H$ then there exists a $y\in l^2$ such that  $Ty=x$. Now we know that $l^2$ has a Schauder basis given by $\{y_n\}$. Then $y$ can be written as $\sum_n a_ny_n=y$. Which means $$T(\sum_n a_ny_n)=\sum_na_n(Ty_n) =x$$
First equality is result of linearity. As you can see, we show that any $x\in H$ can be written as $\sum_na_n(Ty_n)$ (where $\{a_n\}$ is a unique sequence for each $x$) which means $\{Ty_n\}$ is Schauder basis.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer